# JavaScript call function with PHP-Variable as transfer parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am calling the JavaScript-function getElementById. As transfer parameter I want to use the PHP-Variable `$currentTab`

```
var currentTab = document.getElementById(<?php $currentTab ?>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes, and output your variable with `echo`. Maybe add the `#` character if it is not in your php variable

```
document.getElementById('<?php echo $currentTab; ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'` or `"` around `<?php $currentTab ?>`, for `getElementById()` accept a string. And in javascript a string is surrended by `'` or `"`.